# $G$ have a normal series such that the factor groups are abelian.

Tags: group-theory

I see the link:
[Show that a finite group $G$ whose composition factors are of prime order implies having a normal series such that the factor groups are abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309019/show-that-a-finite-group-g-whose-composition-factors-are-of-prime-order-implie)

Let $G$ be a finite group, if all composition factors of $G$ are of prime order, $G$ has a chain of subgroups: $1 = N_0 \triangleleft N_1 \triangleleft N_2 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft N_t=G$ such that each $N_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is abelian.

I have proved:

> (*)a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ is abelian.

Now by the link, KC.'s tips, I let $H_0 = M$, and think about a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $\tilde{H_1}$ of $G/H_0$, by group isomorphism, there must be a group $H_1 \triangleleft G$, and $H_0 \triangleleft H_1, \tilde{H_1} = H_1/H_0$.

If I can prove all composition factors of $G/H_0$ are of prime order, with (*), $H_1/H_0$ is abelian. then use minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $\tilde{H_2}$ of $G/H_1$, and so on, that will be done.

My question is: How to prove all composition factors of $G/H_0$ are of prime order please? or my way is wrong?

Comment: There is a composition series of $G$ that contains $H_0$. The fact that all composition factors of $G/H_0$ are of prime order now follows from the Jordan-Hölder Theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. but I can not understand that.  Jordan-Hölder say for one group the two composition series are 'same'. how to find the composition series of $G/H_0$? and which one is the baseline?

Comment: What do you mean by the baseline? Since $H_0$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, there exists a composition series $1 = M_0 \lhd M_1 \lhd \cdots \lhd M_k = H_0 < M_{k+1} \lhd \cdots \lhd M_n = G$ of $G$ that contains (or passes through) $H_0$. The composition factors of $G$ are $M_{i}/M_{i-1}$ for $1 \le i \le n$ and we are told that they are all  of prime order. Now $M_k/H_0 \lhd M_{k+1}/H_0 \lhd \cdots \lhd M_n/H_0=G/H_0$ is a composition series of $G/H_0$, so the composition factors of $G/H_0$ are $M_{i}/M_{i-1}$ for $k+1\le i \le n$, which are all of prime order.

Comment: @DerekHolt by this, composition factors of $G/H_0$ are $(M_i/H_0)/(M_{i-1}/H_0)$,they are all of prime order, so I can find minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $\tilde{H}_1=H_1/H_0$ of $G/H_0$, and it is abelian, $H_1\lhd G$. above is right because $H_0 = M$ in the composition series of $G$. next step, I want find $\tilde{H}_2=H_2/H_1$ is minimal nontrivial normal subgroup of $G/H_1$. if $(M_i/H_1)/(M_{i-1}/H_1)$ are all of prime order, that is ok. but how can I say $H_1$ still in the composition series of $G$ ($H_1$ is one of $M_i$)?

Comment: Your question was how to prove that the composition factors of $G/H_0$ are of prime order, and I have answered that.